# regexing url parameters IIS

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have reviewed a couple questions on regexing url parameters, but none of which seem to specifically address my issue. I have been trying to work out the correct regex pattern in www.regex101.com and I haven't found any successs. I have a url that has parameters which are separated by `/`'s. I am able to regex one parameter at a time, but I would ideally like to develop a pattern that can extract all of the parameters. So far this is what I have:

`\/([a-zA-z]+)\/([a-zA-z]+)\/([a-zA-z-]+)\/`

The url that I am trying to modify is:

`www.mydomain.com/firstparameter/secondparameter/hyphenated-url-parameter/`

The above pattern works for this example, but I need it to also work for these two examples:

`www.mydomain.com/firstparameter/secondparameter/`

`www.mydomain.com/firstparameter/`

Is it even possible to write one singular regex that can extract the parameters from each example above?

Comment: is the max no. of parameters fixed? do we have more than 3 parameters?

Comment: There are only 3 parameters max, last one is hyphenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `\/([a-zA-z]+)\/(?:(?:([a-zA-z]+)\/)?([a-zA-z-]+)\/)?`

Details:

`? Quantifier`  — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LeyAB8/1)

The assumption here is that, there is at least one parameter and max 3 parameters.

Comment: And that'll do it. So the question marks are there for optionally checking those groups?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any number of parameters:

```
\/([\w|-]+)
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/LeyAB8/2)